Page on reactjs not displaying, coded with javascript
I am currently working on a project with javascript on react but i cannot get the Suggestions page to display what I coded.
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  <Link to="/suggest" className='nav-link'>Submit</Link>
</button>

i have this button on the previous code that takes me to the suggestions page, when I click the button, it does go to the suggestions page but the problem is that it does not display anything but the header for the page. How do I fix this?
this is what I have on the suggestions page:
import React from 'react';
import './ComputerList.scss';

const ComputerList = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container mt-100">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          <div className="card mb-30">
            <div className="card-body text-center">
              <h4 className="card-title">Test Computer</h4>
              <p className="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
              <p>Model: Test Model</p>
              <p>SKU: 123456</p>
              <div className="actions">
                <button>Compare</button>
                <button>Save</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ComputerList;


Why should the ComputerList component display for that route? Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. Specifically include any relevant router code

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

please show your routing file as well to get help tracking your issue.
make sure you have define a route like this:
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ComputerList from "../Components/ComputerList";
const Routing = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
            <Route path="/suggest" element={<ComputerList />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Routing;


App.js code
// App.js

import Routing from "./routes/Routing";

function App() {
  return (
    <Routing />         
  );
}

export default App;


I did not have my route designed, that was the problem. Thank you.

@AdamsHafiz You're welcome! If you have any more questions or need further assistance, feel free to ask. I'm here to help!
